# OnError image handling within php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to handle 404 images pulled from omdbapi.com, but my code is not working. I am looping through an array to build a movie list.

```html
echo '<a href="'.$oIMDB->getUrl().'" target="_new"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail posterImage" onError=\"this.onError=null;this.src='error.png'; this.onclick=null;\" src="https://img.omdbapi.com/?i=' . $user['imdbID'] . '&apikey=secret" height="300"></a>';
```

When I inspect the code in Chrome, it looks like this:

```html
<img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail posterImage" this.onclick="null;\&quot;" height="300" data-pagespeed-url-hash="282594047" src="https://img.omdbapi.com/?i=tt5898034&amp;apikey=secret" onerror="this.onerror=null;pagespeed.lazyLoadImages.loadIfVisibleAndMaybeBeacon(this);" data-pagespeed-lazy-replaced-functions="1">
```

First, I thought the issue was with the single/double quotes inside the echo, but then I saw lazyload appearing in the middle of the onerror.

Is lazyload causing the issue somehow? I haven't deliberately included lazyload on my pages. Maybe it's on by default when jQuery is included?

Any input will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function imageError(e){
 e.setAttribute("src","error.png");
 e.removeAttribute("onError");
 e.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

Add the JavaScript code into your project and edit the PHP :

```
echo '<a href="'.$oIMDB->getUrl().'" target="_new"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail posterImage" onError="imageError(this)" src="https://img.omdbapi.com/?i=' . $user['imdbID'] . '&apikey=secret" height="300"></a>';
```

**OR**

You can edit the PHP like this (without adding custom JavaScript Function):

```
echo '<a href="'.$oIMDB->getUrl().'" target="_new"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail posterImage" onError="this.setAttribute("src","error.png");this.removeAttribute("onError");this.removeAttribute("onclick");" src="https://img.omdbapi.com/?i=' . $user['imdbID'] . '&apikey=secret" height="300"></a>';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.
Image still appears broken.

When I check the code in Chrome, it looks like this:
onerror="this.onerror=null;pagespeed.lazyLoadImages.loadIfVisibleAndMaybeBeacon(this);"

Btw, it seems you missed a $ in front of the e in the imageError function. :)

Comment: Hmm. When I clear the mod_pagespeed cache, chrome reports:
Uncaught ReferenceError: imageError is not defined

I added the function at the top, right after the <?php tag.

Comment: The function is javascript. you can do the other way if you don't know javascript

Answer (score -2):

```
   $t='<img src="img/1facemale.jpg"onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'img/facemale.jpg\';">
   ';
   echo $t;
```